# how can read remaining internal 128MB flash?

Tags: movesense

> Hardware Specification
>
> Sensor model: Movesense "BIG_MEM"
>
> HWCONFIG: SS2_NAND
>
> Data memory: 128 MB FLASH
>
> 1-Wire master:-YES
>
> Remarks:-The movesense sensor variant is BIG_MEM.

I have successfully read the system memory using the command "wbcmd --port COM13 --path System/Memory/Heap --op GET". However, I now need to read the flash memory, which has a capacity of 128 MB. Could you please provide guidance on how to read this memory in the sensor?

I am working on a datalogger in Movesense. When my session is running and recording data in the internal memory (logbook), I want to read the remaining memory.

Answer (score 0):

The data memory accessing is explained in the documentation:

https://www.movesense.com/docs/esw/data_storage/#logbook-service

Comment: Based on the documentation, I noticed that the DataLogger uses the Logbook service to fetch data from EEPROM. However, since we're using Movesense (Sensor model: Movesense "BIG_MEM"), we're forced to use flash memory instead of EEPROM. As a result, flash memory needs to be read instead of EEPROM.

Comment: For flash variant the DataLogger & Logbook use the Flash memory.